# conditional flagging in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a dataframe `df` :-

| ID | 1F_col | 2F_col | 3F_col | 4G_col |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| 3 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 1 |
| 4 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 |
| 5 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 6 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 |

I have 2 types of column names , one which has `F` and another which has `G` in them .

F_type & G_Type : If atleast one of the column names with `F` has 1, I want to flag 1 , and likewise if atleast one of the `G` columns are 1 ,then I want to flag 1(F_type & G_Type are the column names). Like below :

Comm1 :
If both F_type and G_Type is 1 I want to show string `Good`
If F_type is 1 and G_Type is 0 then string `4G`
If F_type is 0 and G_Type is 1 then string `1F`
If both  F_type and G_Type is 0 then string `1F`

Comm2 : If both  F_type and G_Type is 0 then string `Hard`, else `Good` if Comm1 is `Good`, else `Soft`

| ID | F_Type | G_Type | Comm1 | Comm2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | Good | Good |
| 2 | 1 | 0 | 4G | soft |
| 3 | 1 | 1 | Good | Good |
| 4 | 0 | 1 | 1F | Soft |
| 5 | 0 | 0 | 1F | Hard |
| 6 | 1 | 1 | Good | Good |

I have a hug records of `ID` ( 1 million ) what would be the best way to achieve this in less time?

Comment: is `ID` the index of `df` or it is just a simple column?

Comment: Its a column @SalvatoreDanieleBianco

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are working with a larger dataset. One of the approach is to introduce `numpy`.

```py
import numpy as np

df['F_Type'] = df[['1F_col', '2F_col', '3F_col']].any(axis=1).astype(int)
df['G_Type'] = df[['4G_col']].any(axis=1).astype(int)

df['Comm1'] = np.where(df['F_Type'] & df['G_Type'], 'Good', 
                        np.where(df['F_Type'], '4G', '1F'))

df['Comm2'] = np.where(np.logical_and(df['F_Type'] == 0, df['G_Type'] == 0), 
                        'Hard', np.where(df['Comm1'] == 'Good', 'Good', 'Soft'))

print(df)
```

---

```
   ID  1F_col  2F_col  3F_col  4G_col  F_Type  G_Type Comm1 Comm2
0   1       0       1       1       1       1       1  Good  Good
1   2       0       1       0       0       1       0    4G  Soft
2   3       1       1       0       1       1       1  Good  Good
3   4       0       0       0       1       0       1    1F  Soft
4   5       0       0       0       0       0       0    1F  Hard
5   6       1       1       1       1       1       1  Good  Good
```

```
df = df.drop(columns=['1F_col', '2F_col', '3F_col', '4G_col'])
print(df)
```

---

```
   ID  F_Type  G_Type Comm1 Comm2
0   1       1       1  Good  Good
1   2       1       0    4G  Soft
2   3       1       1  Good  Good
3   4       0       1    1F  Soft
4   5       0       0    1F  Hard
5   6       1       1  Good  Good
```

Comment: Is this apprach using row and if / else efficient in terms of  execution time?

Comment: @Scope the only way to know it is testing the code on a larger DataFrame on your machine.

Comment: @Scope You made mentioned of efficiency which is very important I did edited the answer to provide an efficient approach using `numpy`.

Answer (score 1):

```
df_2 = pd.DataFrame(df.ID)
df_2["F_Type"] = (df.loc[:,df.columns.str.match("[0-9]*F_.*")]==1).any(1)
df_2["G_Type"] = (df.loc[:,df.columns.str.match("[0-9]*G_.*")]==1).any(1)

#Comm1
df_2.loc[df_2.F_Type & df_2.G_Type, "Comm1"] = "Good"
df_2.loc[df_2.F_Type & (~df_2.G_Type), "Comm1"] = "4G"
df_2.loc[~df_2.F_Type, "Comm1"] = "1F"

#Comm2
df_2["Comm2"] = df_2.Comm1
df_2.loc[(~df_2[["F_Type","G_Type"]]).all(1), "Comm2"] = "Hard"
df_2.loc[df_2[["F_Type","G_Type"]].sum(1)==1, "Comm2"] = "Soft"

#converting F_type and G_Type in int type
df_2[["F_Type","G_Type"]] = df_2[["F_Type","G_Type"]].astype(int)
df_2
```

Comment: instead of hard coding  for Soft, can the condition be` all except 0 and 0 in "F_Type","G_Type"` can be soft then we can look at comm1 to tag `Good`? I want to prevent hardcoding as much possible

Comment: would .any(1) work the same as sum(1) ?

Comment: @Scope it does not, cause any(1) is true also in case sum is 2 (that would be "Good")

Answer (score 1):

Here is another way:

```
d = {(1,1):['Good','Good'],
(1,0):['4G','soft'],
(0,1):['1F','soft'],
(0,0):['1F','hard']}

df1 = df.set_index('ID').groupby(lambda x: x[1],axis=1).any().astype(int)

df2 = pd.DataFrame(pd.MultiIndex.from_frame(df1).map(d).tolist(),columns = ['Comm1','Comm2'])

final_df = pd.concat([df1.reset_index(),df2],axis=1)
```

or:

```
df1 = df.set_index('ID').groupby(lambda x: '{}_Type'.format(x[1]),axis=1).any().astype(int)
df2 = pd.DataFrame([[0,0,'1F','Hard'],[1,0,'4G','soft'],[0,1,'1F','Soft'],[1,1,'Good','Good']],columns = ['F_Type','G_Type','Comm1','Comm2'])

df = pd.merge(df1,df2,how='left')
```

Ouput:

```
   ID  F  G Comm1 Comm2
0   1  1  1  Good  Good
1   2  1  0    4G  soft
2   3  1  1  Good  Good
3   4  0  1    1F  soft
4   5  0  0    1F  hard
5   6  1  1  Good  Good
```